# jquery find not working in firefox / safari

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, safari, find

I am working on a search script that search in elements to a value..
This is working in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox nor Safari.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I guess it is in my find function, but I don't know how to solve it...

My code:

```
    $(function () {
    $.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
    };

    //Actieve zoekfunctie
    function zoek_user(list) {
        $(".zoekbinnencloud")
        .change( function () {
            //Haal waarde op
            var searchtext = $(this).val();
            if(searchtext) {
                //Zoek naar content in lijst
                $matches = $(list).find("[data-username^='"+searchtext+"'");
                //Verberg niet matchende data
                $('img', list).not($matches).slideUp();
                //Laat matchende data zien
                $matches.slideDown();

            } else {
                //Als we niet zoeken laat alles zien
                $(list).find("img").slideDown(200);
            }
            return false;
        })
        .keyup( function (e) {
            $(this).change().preventDefault();
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        zoek_user($("div#cloud"));
    });
}($));
});
```

The cloud div

```
<div id="cloud"><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000672819298/abb050ce55a7677889347e7089141159_normal.jpeg" data-username="bs_stokhasselt" data-onclick="BS_Stokhasselt&Vandaag waren #studenten van #fontys #PABO #Tilburg op bezoek! http://t.co/GZAxAhg7vs" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1794380911/NienkeMeijer2012-2klein_normal.jpg" data-username="nienke meijer" data-onclick="NienkeMeijer1&@Fontys CvB tour #IT Goede discussie  ontzorging #onderwijs Studenten zijn toekomstige collega's en verdienen een professionele IT omgeving!" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1789328274/logo_large_nl_normal.png" data-username="kamers in amsterdam" data-onclick="Kamers_Adam&@Fontys Zoek je een kamer in Amsterdam? Ik kan helpen! Op http://t.co/Az0m75gny9 vind je een overzicht van alle kamers in Amsterdam" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000364169902/0a2da96e562ec822e19e21ed5acd0286_normal.jpeg" data-username="ka-an" data-onclick="kaaaaatjee&@Rozux3 http://t.co/u7f6ZpJC6a zeg ik je " /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000834060716/77c9fa418c6c7411733b2ce032e2fd3d_normal.jpeg" data-username="dionne" data-onclick="DionnedeVroomen&Net thuis van super interessante module op de fontys in Veghel. Geluisterd naar een boeiend verhaal over het beroep leraar." /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000472824741/3407bfe5a6a3644881836869a84bc50b_normal.png" data-username="fontysbent" data-onclick="FontysBEnT&De #zonsondergang vanuit #Fontys R1 bekijken... mooi! Alle harde werkers van #FontysBEnT kunnen even genieten zo! http://t.co/IxClnkC44E" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1628543361/pen_cj_normal.jpg" data-username="cees-jan pen" data-onclick="CeesJanPen&Mooie gesprekken bij @FontysBrainport: volgende leegstand leeft meeting Helmond, #Fontys vastgoeddebat GR2014 en opzet afstudeeronderzoeken" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000757624505/352479ad3d9bdf04e945608f9ab47139_normal.jpeg" data-username="high tech nl" data-onclick="verenigingHTNL&Is er een relatie tussen hightech en autisme? High Tech NL en Fontys @marlouheskes zoeken het uit. http://t.co/9XPBnIz6X0" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2998263908/f9838363be563b9c3a633784b555ee9a_normal.jpeg" data-username="areaconsult" data-onclick="AreaConsult&Bij #fontys hogeschool luisteren naar #Horizon2020 #subsidie aanvraag #healthsector voor #MKB en #kennisinstellingen #pps!" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000472824741/3407bfe5a6a3644881836869a84bc50b_normal.png" data-username="fontysbent" data-onclick="FontysBEnT&Meeloopdag #FontysPTH was goed bevallen. Ook kijken bij miniworkshopjes? Bezoek de #Fontys open dag op 26 januari! http://t.co/JZHFmcQB0v" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000660693911/ce8f46406e8f16228b1e396e928e12e0_normal.jpeg" data-username="jeroen" data-onclick="roensel&En daarbij, Fontys, even een voorbeeld van een wat betere implementatie: https://t.co/xu1mJSeW0p — heeft nog geen uur gekost om op te zetten" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/412963769338580993/_QeS9dze_normal.jpeg" data-username="shiromani" data-onclick="ShiromaniR&Vandaag presentatie gehad bij een top leraar @Richard013 hij inspireert toch echt wel! En NEE dat is geen geslijm #HRM #fontys" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000660693911/ce8f46406e8f16228b1e396e928e12e0_normal.jpeg" data-username="jeroen" data-onclick="roensel&Lieve Fontys. Toen ik zei dat jullie SSL implementatie een faal was, doelde ik niet alleen op SSLv2 die aanstond... http://t.co/9tPZdte5AR" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/415904531797794816/kNgH-8NZ_normal.jpeg" data-username="delly" data-onclick="D_Issa99&RT @Bram_Coolen: fontys te saai" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000825638439/f1ba88d4df574645c3e3c86e3fe83922_normal.jpeg" data-username="b��am��oolen™" data-onclick="Bram_Coolen&fontys te saai" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000451209527/17274ae641ff5cedc17fd31bd98ab427_normal.jpeg" data-username="math. strijbos" data-onclick="MathStrijbos&@Autisme_Fontys Dank voor de RT." /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1586373146/Afbeelding_024_normal.JPG" data-username="autisme_fontysoso" data-onclick="Autisme_Fontys&RT @AvansHogeschool: #vacature Medewerker evenementenorganisatie / baliemedewerker http://t.co/02DHIuFryf" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3295879910/4706a1ac8daede4d6ae20020968a5b15_normal.jpeg" data-username="eefke" data-onclick="Story_beelden&RT @FontysLifestyle: Jongerentrends 2014 http://t.co/lwkom9I4ZR  van @JongEnJeWilWat #trends #jongeren #2014 #fontysILS #fontysACI #fontys" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1586373146/Afbeelding_024_normal.JPG" data-username="autisme_fontysoso" data-onclick="Autisme_Fontys&RT @TUeindhoven: Interview met prof Maarten Steinbuch (@M_Steinbuch) over zorgrobots die van elkaar leren |Met Het Oog Op Morgen http://t.c…" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1586373146/Afbeelding_024_normal.JPG" data-username="autisme_fontysoso" data-onclick="Autisme_Fontys&RT @MathStrijbos: In de #huisartsgeneeskunde, of liever breder nog, in alle gelederen van de zorg, is #communicatie het #sleutelwoord. # ar…" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1694582772/fontys_small_72px_normal.jpg" data-username="fontys hogescholen" data-onclick="Fontys&De Ruimte voor Innovatie scriptieprijs, voor hbo-studenten met een scriptie over innovatie in de gezondheidszorg. http://t.co/UnJILpiu9Q" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000386518329/2080d26e361633a53b80323df7dc4e18_normal.jpeg" data-username="maud bouwman" data-onclick="MaudBouwman&Collega's Planning&amp;amp;Control van andere Fontys locaties ontvangen @PaboVenlo ter afsluiting van hun studieochtend @FontysVenlo. #denkgroter" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1694582772/fontys_small_72px_normal.jpg" data-username="fontys hogescholen" data-onclick="Fontys&Is de NBN-Rabobankscriptieprijs iets voor jou? Inschrijven tot 15 februari. Info http://t.co/NPqERXqloL #bedrijfsethiek #maatsch verantwoord" /><img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3366562939/793105a26a2e2d0889d44b2a98b1e842_normal.png" data-username="werkenbijfontys" data-onclick="WerkenbijFontys&Next step? #Fontys #ACI heeft leuke vacatures! Kijk op http://t.co/ZEoV9htLwO voor de mogelijkheden" /></div>
```

The search is a simple input..

But the weird thing is, it is working in Chrome and ie..

Maybe someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any error in console? Looks like an error here: `$(this).change().preventDefault();`

Comment: True, but when i remove the preventdefault.. It still works only is chrome and ie..  not in safari/ff

Comment: You may have to put on window.load check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850701/jquery-find-not-working-in-safari