# jQuery .find not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

this works fine in Firefox and Chrome. But why not in Safari?

```
 $('.bxslider li .image').each(function() {
   $(this).width($(this).find('img').width());
    });
```

The result in Safari is `style="width: 0px; "`.
Also tried $(document).ready, no change.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the image might not be loaded yet

Comment: Try this code inside $(window).load()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested use the `window.load()` handler to run the code after all the images are loaded.

Or use

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.bxslider li .image img').load(function () {
        $(this).closest('.image').width(this.width)
    }).filter(function () {
        return this.complete;
    }).trigger('load')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code inside `$(window).load(function() { })` to make sure all the images are loaded properly before changing the width.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.bxslider li .image').each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).find('img').width());
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this before and it did not work. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

instead of find you can also use the ">"-operator.
E.g.:

```
$('.bxslider li .image').each(function() {
   $(this).width($(this+'> img').width());
    });
```

You can also use this operator in CSS:
E.g.:

```
body > h1
```

match all h1-Tags inside the body-Tag.